# Full size of videojs

Tags: html, css, video.js

I have `div` on specific width (100%) and I'd like to inside this place `videojs`. But when I use `height="auto"` and `width="auto"` it doesn't work. I try also:

```
.vjs-tech {
   position: relative !important;
}
```

But then my `.video-js` `div` is 4px higher than `.vjs-tech` `div`.

I just do this:

```
.vjs-control-bar {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

But it's not clean solution, so please help me ;)

***EDIT***

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8aexa3ag/

That `divs` don't have the same height:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add more code samples here or use jsfiddle to provide a sample.

Comment: I checked your jsfiddle, and i see the video is aligned with the div. Not sure what you are seeing that you want to change. Need more info with the html piece as well, the div tag.

Comment: @bbh `<div class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-paused vjs-controls-enabled vjs-user-inactive" id="example_video_1">` is not the same size as `<video id="example_video_1_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" preload="auto" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"  src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4">` and I really want to make it identical ;)

Comment: The question is why are you trying to achieve this? What bug/UX issue is it causing?